# Attempt to get length of null array on PageFragment

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, ondestroy, fragmentmanager

I have this app that shows a help with **com.cleveroad.slidingtutorial library**

I follow the documentation accord to android.app.Fragment

But I stuck with this error always when close or slide screen to the next pagefragment. I tried with 1 page and more and always get the same error **Attempt to get length of null array**

Version of slidingtutorial on gradle com.cleveroad:slidingtutorial:1.0.8

Sliding tutorial guide [Cleveroad/SlidingTutorial-Android](https://github.com/Cleveroad/SlidingTutorial-Android/wiki/Configure-Tutorial-Pages)

MainActivityTutorialCrearContacto  class

```
public class MainActivityTutorialCrearContacto extends Activity {
    public UsuarioDao usuario;
    public Typeface typeface_bold, typeface_regular;
    private int[] mPagesColors;
    private static final int TOTAL_PAGES = 1;
    private static final int ACTUAL_PAGES_COUNT = 3;
    private final String TAG = MainActivityTutorialCrearContacto.class.getSimpleName();


    public static void start(Context context) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivityTutorialCrearContacto.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_tutorial);

        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        try {
            typeface_regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), Constantes.TYPEFACE_FONT_OPENSANS_REGULAR);
            typeface_bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), Constantes.TYPEFACE_FONT_OPENSANS_SEMIBOLD);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mPagesColors = new int[]{
                getResources().getColor(R.color.color_fondo_green_dark)
//                ,getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
//                ,getResources().getColor(R.color.color_fondo_orange_pido )
        };

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            replaceTutorialFragment();
        }
    }


    final TutorialPageProvider<Fragment> tutorialPageProvider = new TutorialPageProvider<Fragment>() {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment providePage(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0: {
                    return new ContactoFirstragment();
                }
                case 1: {
                    return new ContactoFirstragment();
                }
                case 2: {
                    return new ContactoThirdFragment();
                }

                default: {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown position: " + position);
                }
            }
        }
    };


    public void replaceTutorialFragment() {

        try {


            final IndicatorOptions indicatorOptions = IndicatorOptions.newBuilder(this)
                    .build();
            final TutorialOptions tutorialOptions = TutorialFragment.newTutorialOptionsBuilder(this)
                    .setUseAutoRemoveTutorialFragment(false)
                    .setUseInfiniteScroll(false)
                    .setPagesColors(mPagesColors)
                    .setPagesCount(TOTAL_PAGES)
                    .setIndicatorOptions(indicatorOptions)
                    .setTutorialPageProvider(tutorialPageProvider)
                    .setOnSkipClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Util.guardarPreferencia(Constantes.VERTUTORIAL_CONTACTO, "ENTENDIDO", getApplicationContext());
                            try {
                                //getFragmentManager().popBackStack(); // THIS DON'T CLOSE DE ACTIVITY
                                finish();
                                // cierraFragmentTransaction();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .build();
            final TutorialFragment tutorialFragment = TutorialFragment.newInstance(tutorialOptions);
            getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, tutorialFragment)
                    .commit();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

> PageFragment Class

```
class ContactoSecondFragment extends PageFragment {
    TextView tv_hola, textView_solicitaremail, textView2, textView1;
    public UsuarioDao usuario;
    DatabaseManager manager;
    public Typeface typeface_bold, typeface_regular;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Context ctx = getContext();
        try {
            typeface_regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), Constantes.TYPEFACE_FONT_OPENSANS_REGULAR);
            typeface_bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), Constantes.TYPEFACE_FONT_OPENSANS_SEMIBOLD);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacto_fragment_page_second, container, false);
        findViews(view);

        try {
            if(typeface_bold!=null && typeface_regular!=null) {
                tv_hola.setTypeface(typeface_bold);
                textView1.setTypeface(typeface_regular);
                textView2.setTypeface(typeface_regular);
                textView_solicitaremail.setTypeface(typeface_regular);
            }

            checkDatabaseManager();
            UsuarioDao usuario = manager.obtenerUsuario();
            String nombre = WordUtils.capitalize(usuario.getNombre().toLowerCase());
            tv_hola.setText("Hola " + nombre + "\n ¡Vamos a ayudarte!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tv_hola.setText("Hola  ¡Vamos a ayudarte!");
        }
        return view;
    }

    private void findViews(View view) {
        tv_hola = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView0_hola);
        textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView_solicitaremail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_solicitaremail);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResId() {
        return R.layout.contacto_fragment_page_second;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected TransformItem[] getTransformItems() {
        return new TransformItem[]{
                TransformItem.create(R.id.textView0_hola, Direction.RIGHT_TO_LEFT, 0.2f),
                TransformItem.create(R.id.img_hola, Direction.LEFT_TO_RIGHT, 0.6f),
                TransformItem.create(R.id.textView1, Direction.RIGHT_TO_LEFT, 0.8f),
                TransformItem.create(R.id.textView2, Direction.LEFT_TO_RIGHT, 0.10f),
                TransformItem.create(R.id.img_email, Direction.RIGHT_TO_LEFT, 0.3f),
                TransformItem.create(R.id.textView_solicitaremail, Direction.LEFT_TO_RIGHT, 0.9f)
        };
    }


    private void checkDatabaseManager() {
        try {
            if (manager == null) {
                DatabaseManager.init(getContext());
                manager = DatabaseManager.getInstance();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Error

> Attempt to get length of null array

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
at com.cleveroad.slidingtutorial.PageImpl.onDestroyView(PageImpl.java:71)
at com.cleveroad.slidingtutorial.PageFragment.onDestroyView(PageFragment.java:73)
at android.app.Fragment.performDestroyView(Fragment.java:2570)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1061)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.detachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1351)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:798)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1580)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:483)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to destroy activity with slidingtutorial library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987164/unable-to-destroy-activity-with-slidingtutorial-library)